# Build comma-separated list of rows from SQL results

Tags: python

I am new to python and have setup pymssql to execute a stored procedure as per commonly found examples:

```
cur.execute("EXEC [dbo].[GetIPList]")

row = cur.fetchone()
while row:
    print "%s" % (row[0])
    row = cur.fetchone()
```

I want to build a variable which is a comma separated list of all rows.

If I use "cur.fetchall"  instead of "cur.fetchone" I get a tuple which I am not sure how to use in the subprocess.

What's the best approach to be taking here ?

Comment: `','.join(tuple_of_rows)`

Comment: And to cite Guido von Rossum: 'Nobody should be using python 2 anymore'. If you are new to python and do not need to rely on old code, use python 3.

Comment: @MaxNoe, close, but not quite, since each row is itself a tuple. That precise code with a tuple of tuples (or a list of tuples) won't come out quite right.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about the nested tuples

Comment: ... did you want a comma separated list of all rows, or of item 0 (`row[0]`) in each row? Since row itself is a tuple, a comma separated list of rows would be a comma separated list of tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
s = ','.join([ r[0] for r in cur.fetchall() ])
```

Comment: You do not need the list comprehension, a generator is enough.

Comment: @MaxNoe, ...to be sure, both will work, but the former is easier to decompose and inspect, being stateless as it is.

Comment: The object is directly consumed by the `join`. Why create the list? It just adds to unnecessary symbols and creates an unneeded and potentially large object.

Comment: @MaxNoe, as I said, the point is letting the OP look at what's going on the code. They can run, say, `res=[ r[0] for r in cur.fetchall() ]` at a REPL, and then look at `res`, then use it for the join call at their REPL. Use a genexp, and inspecting it consumes its results, meaning you can't both inspect an instance at the REPL and then use it again.

Comment: @MaxNoe, ...it's not what I'd do if I were trying to write maximally efficient code, but I'm trying to write maximally discoverable / beginner-friendly code right now.

Comment: ... so @MaxNoe's comment was quite valuable as it lets the reader see the more optimal solution. Thanks Max!

Comment: @tdelaney, definitely! Incidentally, this is one of the things I like about Clojure's lazy sequences, as opposed to Python generators -- a lazy seq keeps a pointer to its head, so as long as there's still a reference to it the contents are cached, whereas just iterating over it without keeping a reference to the head lets items be discarded from memory after use, so you get to have it both ways: Items are transient [and non-GCable memory use constant] if you can't possibly reuse the object later (no references to the head), or cached and inspectable if you can.